# Is demo account mandatory for apple submission?

Tags: ios, itunes-store

Im actually getting ready to post my app to iTunes .

The app is a WiFi based app and it is dependent on an other hardware device to be up and running in the same WiFi network. So without this hardware device the user will not be able to login into the app and use it.

Hence I would not be able to provide in a demo account to Apple as they will not be having the needed hardware with them.

So the question is that, Will my app get rejected if the demo account is not provided?

Comment: This is not a Question for this forum, but i would say YES, it will get rejected.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for your answer . Can you please explain why is this an inappropriate question for this forum.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about submitting an app to Apple, not programming an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My app was rejected because of that. So we had to find a way to let Apple test the whole app. The easiest way will be to provide a demo mode which enable/simulate all of your feature.

Answer (score 3):

I recently went through a similar situation with my company. We have hardware that the app connects with and controls so we had to make a demo account for Apple to use that used hardware in our office in order for them to go through the app.

With hardware you will also be forced to either send your hardware in for apple to test with the app so they can see it actually working with the app or create a video that shows the app interacting with the hardware.

I think that it will depend on what hardware you have and how the app works but we were able to get our app approved by just making a video that demonstrates the app and hardware working together.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you need to register your hardware for [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). After that you can upload your app in App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - If your app requires login then yes unless no.

Descriptive answer - If your app needs some type of login then you are required to submit a demo account using which app QA engineers can test your app before approving it. It is necessary for them because they test around 700 apps in a day and out of those more than 50% apps requires a login. It is nearly impossible for them to create new accounts with pre-filled data to test app. For example If your app has subscription of 10 USD per month then they are not going make in-app purchase to test that feature.