# Application rejected - no demo account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an application with banking domain (UPI) the very first step or screen the user is presented with a button titled "SEND SMS" to login/register when user clicks on it, a SMS is send from the device using the MFMessageComposeViewController, and based on the mobile number the server respond with weather the user already exists or its a new registration.

Since this is obvious that a valid phone number is required to send SMS or use the application, I am unable to provide a demo account to them.

This is second release of the version, for the first release we have submitted the video of production application and it was live on Appstore, not only this app but I have submitted few other without a demo account but using a video, this time too I have submitted the video, still they ask for the demo account, I have tried to explain them whole process using telephone conversation but no luck. Also did asked them to use there own mobile number on their testing device but they refused to do so.

How can I move forward with this release?

I went through some similar question but didn't find any help.

1. [Apple rejects app because test account not given (as App login via OTP only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453416/apple-rejects-app-because-test-account-not-given-as-app-login-via-otp-only)
2. [Is demo account mandatory for apple submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648109/is-demo-account-mandatory-for-apple-submission)
3. [App meta data rejected , requires demo account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319961/app-meta-data-rejected-requires-demo-account).

*Note: I don't have OTP functionality in my application, the only way to register is by sending the SMS*.

Comment: At some point one of our apps had the same issue, Apple made us build an other way to login in.

Comment: at the bottom line, you have to provide a demo account – or any other way what lets them bypass the login barrier and can have access to the app's features.

Comment: exactly - however it's well worth noting that **you don't have to knock yourself out, making the 'apple review version' as complete as the real app.**  The Apple reviewers just GLANCE at the app.  If it looks professional and doesn't crash-on-launch, you're all set.  In fact: I usually carefully spy on exactly what the apple review looks at, and every time it has been "almost nothing" - just a glance, often just one screen and that's it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this annoying situation.

The fact is, generally you have to:

**change your app, so that it *does have* a demo mode, which Apple can use.**

It's a total pain in the ass but that's how it is.

Some points,

- For example, you could have a "special" number (666-777-8888) which is entered. When that one is entered, the app unlocks and you can see how it works.
- It is really bad luck when this happens.  It's just one of the reviewers being an idiot.  Sometimes if you just submit again it will sail through.
- Note that you CAN IN FACT email them and explain the situation, **they will give you special handling and they will "actually test it" with a phone number**.  However, of course **this can take time, it takes a long time to get special handling**.  (Unless your app is already popular / well-known, then they will help you instantly. It's not fair but that's life.)
- An important point is this: for the demo mode, note that you **do not have to** go overboard showing every feature. Apple's review process is a joke anyway. In 99.9% of cases they just glance at your app. **If you do have to make an 'Apple demo mode', it's normal that the demo mode only has a few of your features.** They are really just checking that it does not crash-upon-launch and that it generally works ok.

{Regarding the last point - indeed they only carefully review your app for policy problems etc once it is popular. This leads to the infuriating situation where controversial apps are approved at first, but then once they "actually look at it" they say you're not allowed to collect donations or use that payment model or whatever the case may be.}

Regarding having a "special demo" mode.  It's a nuisance but sometimes you have to do this:

1. Have a URL like "yourCompany.com/DemoCheck.txt".
2. When the app launches, see if that exists.
3. If it does, allow "pain in the ass Apple demo mode"
4. Now, after apple approves it, in fact remove the URL from your web server, so your app now knows to run in normal consumer mode.

(Note that if you are using any sort of backend, which you probably are, you can do the same thing just using your back end.  So just have a value in Firebase or whatever that indicates "Apple demo mode". Once the app goes to production, turn it off.)

Once again, if you're truly doing something important like "a banking app" you, obviously can't have a security hole like an idiotic "apple test version".  In that case you **can actually** contact them and carefully explain the situation and they will, in fact, test it "properly" using a phone etc.  But that takes a *really* long time and is just not practical - consider, you'd have to do that every single time.  In practice you need a "apple demo mode".

Comment: Awesome answer, I would add that you can enable the "demo" mode using a firebase configuration or a configuration on your API that will simply ignore the phone validation, and you can disable it when the app is approved so no one would break the app in production.

Comment: Exactly @danypata (indeed, I think I even mention Firebase in passing in the above) - almost all non-trivial apps these days are using Firebase, or similar, and it's (unfortunately in a way!) very easy to pander to Apple Reviewers, in this manner.

Comment: It's worth noting - no point being coy about it - **this is exactly how people today sneak controversial features past Apple's comic review process**.  You have an "apple review" version of the app, and once it passes review, you "turn on" the actual app, with a Firebase toggle  :O   That's the reality.  Everyone does it.  Hopefully Apple's not reading this  :)

Comment: One thing that is problematic when using firebase (I had this issue before), there are countries that banned Firebase (Chine is the best example) so in this case, you have to implement it on your API. TBH, it's kind of paintful to see how Apple treats the platform developers.

Comment: I literally did not know FBase was blocked in China, holy crap!  :)

Comment: Me neither, until we got bug reports from the China representative saying the app is full of things that shouldn't be there. Things that were configured using firebase :)).

Comment: Thanks @Fattie, thanks for the awesome reply. The application is indeed a banking application, and providing a demo account could leave a security loophole within the application, i had at-least thrice a time telephonic conversation with one of the member of the team, but the hard thing is that they are not all ready to understand the case. i wrote them on resolution center,  the only response is they a need demo account :(, Is there any document or any sample or content that i should include in an appeal, if so please help me by providing the same.

Comment: Hmm, that's bad news!  Did you reply "the only way to generate a demo account on this app is to use a telephone number to generate a OTP" ......

Comment: Yes, indeed i did reply